# Receive count of MySQL requests from a certain host

Tags: mysql

I want to get the count of MySQL connections on a host using,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.PROCESSLIST where host='hostname';
```

But my host has a different number after each connection looking like port #s. This makes it impossible to match the host name. What can I do to match the hosts without taking these ports into account?

They look like:

```
Hostname:1212

Hostname:1214
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to create a MySQL view that would contain your data plus a new column called host. That new column's value would be based off of the host values you currently have e.g. hostname:1234 and it would use either of [substring](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_substring.asp) or better yet [substring_index](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_substring_index.asp) to go from host:1234 to host.

Try this SELECT statement to see whether that works

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.PROCESSLIST where SUBSTRING_INDEX(host, ":", 1)='hostname';
```

You can then do GROUP BY and get the COUNT(host) correctly.